# Does the Terra Mystica app implement the official rules updates?

Tags: terra-mystica

I've been playing the Terra Mystica app on Android, and I noticed that the rules description on the Cultists' ability didn't include the updated text (if everybody declines taking power when you could have earned a cult point from it, you gain a power). I played a game as them, but the AI never turned down the power, so I couldn't tell if the rule was implemented without the text update. This update was made after the second edition printing.

This also got me wondering if the game setup includes the errata for the scoring tile setup, forbidding the spade points tile on turns 5 and 6. This update was included in the second edition printing.

Does the app include either/both of these updates?

Comment: [This player](https://videogamegeek.com/article/25689624#25689624) reports that cultists are implemented properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The Terra Mystic App (on Android at least) includes the changes to Cultist Power and the variable starting Victory Points.

It does not block the Spade tiles in the last two rounds.

The above is based on my experience playing the app as of August 2017.
Edited to reflect recieving [5 points for founding town/4 earth cult for a Spade] as my final round token in a game in late August.

Comment: Hi Jontia, thanks for your answer! Could you possibly add a note on how you've discovered this, either from another source or just from experience?